# android gallery view change alpha value

Tags: android, view, gallery, alpha-transparency

I am making an android gallery. I want to be able to extend it's basic behavior so the view that its centered to be most visible (it's alpha value to be 1.0) and the views that are from the left and to the right to have some minimum visibility which will increase if the user scrolls and positions a particular view in the center. 
I am wondering if someone has done this before, or has an idea how I should try and do this.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this, but did something similar utilizing data from the central item in the gallery.  What I did was simply create my own adapter

```
YourAdapter extends BaseAdapter{...}
```

Now you can set a externel listener or have the adapter listen to the gallery

```
//listen for user events on Gallery
gallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(YourAdapter);
```

in the adapter create these functions

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    selectedItem = position;
    }


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //change according if selected or not
            if(position == selectedItem)
                //set the alpha for selected
            else
                //set the alpha for other items
    }
```

Comment: hope that was clear, I intentionally left a lot to fill in the blanks so you can customize to your needs.

Comment: I went with overriding the getChildStaticTransformation method of the Gallery class, because i had it implemented already. And made some calculations to change the alpha value regarding the distance from the center of the gallery. Your solution worked also, but the changing of the alpha value was more sudden, and with this changed continuously. But thx, anyway:)

Comment: oh that's good to know, using the native Android tools is always ideal as apposed to implementing your own effects.  Great solution, will keep in mind if I ever need it.